# Different Amazon EC2 instances with same IP

Tags: networking, ip, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cdn

I am looking at building something similar to a CDN and am wondering if it would be possible to do this with EC2 instances, setting their IP address to be the same?

I would like to use the [Anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) approach to a CDN - i.e. multiple servers in different locations all responding to the same IP; the fastest one to respond actually serving the file(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do this in EC2. You can only assign an Elastic IP address to one instance at once. Building an Anycast network needs a degree of control over your netblocks and BGP routing tables that you can't get in EC2. You could use Amazon's CloudFront CDN instead of building your own, of course. Or you could use their Route53 latency-based DNS aliases to do something similar at the DNS level instead of at the IP level.

Comment: Ah yes ok, that makes sense. Thanks very much for your Route53 suggestion - I think I'm actually going to do that! Yes I could buy CDN but I've written a CDN style algorithm I'm keen to try out :)

Comment: Do you know of any IAAS that provides the ability to create your own anycast network?